# Swift Auto layout in multiple device

Tags: swift, layout

i have a problem with auto layout.

[SCREEN HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMjmr.jpg)

In the right part of the image (4.7 inch iphone 6) all my label are on the right place.

but when i change like iphone 6 plus or iphone 5 the label are not good

it's a View -> inside an imageView -> inside some label

The strange is if i have no contraints the label are on the right place for eatch device... but too small

Is it possible to have success to have one design or do i must have 3 design (1 for Iphone 6S, 1 for Iphone 6, 1 for Iphone 5) to have quality ?

Ty for help

Best Regards

Comment: You can set specific Autolayout constant using DeviceLayout https://github.com/cruisediary/DeviceLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem in several ways.

In this case, From my experience, I suggest you to use a subview that contains UIImage and UILabels.

In the subview, you can give a clear constraints to image and labels.

I hope this could be an help for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's that i did...

i have a xib file with a view. Inside i have imageView and label... i did Add missing contraints for auto layout... and the result in on my screenshoot

I ask if i can fix this with one view or may i have to make 3 views for iphone 6s, iphone 6 and iphone 5

i'm not sure of that